# How can I update the a list of items in React without refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My code has a form that can be filled up and once the form is filled up, the credentials of that form is displayed on the employees' portal. However, the website needs to be refreshed in order for the new entries to be displayed.

Here's my useReducer.

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const FireInsuranceContext = createContext();

export const FireInsuranceReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_FIREINSURANCES":
      return {
        fireInsurances: action.payload,
      };
    case "CREATE_FIREINSURANCE":
      return {
        fireInsurances: [action.payload, ...state.fireInsurances],
      };
    case "DELETE_FIREINSURANCE":
      return {
        fireInsurances: state.fireInsurances.filter(
          (f) => f._id !== action.payload._id
        ),
      };
    case "RESOLVE_FIREINSURANCE":
      return {
        fireInsurances: state.fireInsurances.map((fire) =>
          fire._id === action.payload._id 
            ? { ...fire, resolved: action.payload.resolved }
            : fire
        ),
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const FireInsuranceContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(FireInsuranceReducer, {
    fireInsurances: [],
  });

  return (
    <FireInsuranceContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </FireInsuranceContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Here is the formhandler function for the form

```
const formHandler = async (e) => {
//other stuff

try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:2213/api/fire-emailer", {
        mode: "cors",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      });

      const json = await response.json();
      if (!response.ok) {
        setError(json.error);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(json.error);
      }
      if(response.ok) {
        dispatch({ type: "CREATE_FIREINSURANCE", payload: json });
        console.log("workoutadded", json)
        setNotif(true);
        setLoading(false);
        setError("");
        setName("");
        setAddress("");
        setContact("");
        setEmail("");
        setCompany("");
        setInfrastructure("");
        setConstruction("");
      }

      console.log(json);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setError("An error occurred. Please try again later.");
      setLoading(false);
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the display of forms

```
const FireInsuranceList = () => {
  const { fireInsurances, dispatch } = useContext(FireInsuranceContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFireInsurance = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:2213/api/getInsurance/fire-insurance",
        {
          mode: "cors",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_FIREINSURANCES", payload: json });
        console.log("useEffect ran")
      }
    };
    fetchFireInsurance();
  },[dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="px-2 mt-3">
      <div className="flex justify-between flex-wrap">
        <div className="flex gap-x-2">
          <form className="relative">
            <input
              className="border border-gray-800 rounded-md text-sm p-1"
              placeholder="Search Name"
              type="search"
            />
            <button className="absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 right-1">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} />
            </button>
          </form>
          <select className="text-sm p-1 rounded-md border-gray-800 border bg-white">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="solved">Solved</option>
            <option value="unresolved">Unresolved</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <h3 className="font-bold">Fire Insurance Inquiries</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        {fireInsurances.length !== 0 ? (
          <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-around gap-3 my-10">
            {fireInsurances.map((fireInsurance) => (
              <FireInsuranceDetails
                key={fireInsurance._id}
                fireInsurance={fireInsurance}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="text-center text-xl font-bold mt-10 text-gray-700">
            No Fire Insurance Inquiries
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FireInsuranceList;
```

Comment: Inside "formHandler" function use: e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

if i understood right, that's normal because you are indeed creation the fireInsurance, but your useEffect is run only on first render (since dispatch never changes) so you will only get the already saved fire insurances and if you add `fireInsurances` to the dependencies you will get an infinite re-renders. The way to go is to call `fetchFireInsurance` onSuccess of the form handler.

Comment: is there a dependency that I can use to re-render the list when something is added?

Comment: You can but you will need to add multiple properties to your reducer state, and its a bad practice to do so (triggering the effect from the handler).
Just define the function `fetchFireInsurance` outside the useEffect, call it in the useEffect as you already do but just on the first render, and call it also in your formHandler after the creation is success like so :

`if(response.ok) {
        dispatch({ type: "CREATE_FIREINSURANCE", payload: json });
   await fetchFireInsurance()
`

Comment: I think I found the problem. Basically, I opened two instance of the website. One of the instance is on the list of fire insurance page and the other one is on the form if the insurance page (responsible for adding). I added an insurance through the form and the list from the other instance did not update. Is it because another instance of a website does not update another instance of a website through useReducer?